# Cannot Set Properties on MailItem

Tags: vba, outlook, rules, mailitem

I have setup a rule to run `yuno` on anything with "Test1" as the subject (I restarted after setting this up):
[image]

My code looks like this:

```
Sub yuno(ByRef mymail As MailItem)
    mymail.MarkAsTask olMarkToday
    mymail.TaskDueDate = Now
    mymail.ReminderSet = True
    Debug.Print "Y U NO?"
End Sub
```

"Y U NO" prints on receipt of an email with "Test1" as the subject, but it does not receive the little red flag in Outlook. [Degustaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3897316/degustaf) said that this code would correctly flag the item here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26722857/2642059 But it appears that the problem is in running it as a rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest there is a missing

```
mymail.Save
```

Comment: Fantastic, that solves it. So I have other macro code that marks a `MailItem` as read and moves it to another folder, and that never executes, `mymail.Save`. Is there a reason that that works and this does not?

Comment: MailItem.Move creates and **saves** the item in the target folder.